# Where does getopt_long store an unrecognized option?

Tags: c, getopt-long

When `getopt` or `getopt_long` encounters an illegal option, it stores the offending option character in `optopt`. When the illegal option is a *long* option, where can I find out what the option was? And does anything meaningful get stored in `optopt` then?

I've set `opterr = 0` to suppress the automatically printed error message. I want to create my own message that I can print or log where I'd like, but I want to include the name of the unrecognized option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest I can find is that if you get a `BADCH` return the `argv` item that caused it is in `argv[optind-1]`.  Seems like there should be a better way to find the problem argument.

Answer (score 7):

You're quite right that the man page glosses right over these details, but enough hints can be gleaned from the source code, e.g., glibc's implementation in glibc-x.y.z/posix/getopt.c's `_getopt_internal_r`.  (Perhaps that's the only interesting implementation of this GNU extension function?)

That code sets `optopt` to 0 when it encounters an erroneous long option, which I guess is useful to distinguish this case from an erroneous short option, when `optopt` will surely be non-NUL.

The error messages produced when `opterr != 0` mostly print out the erroneous long option as `argv[optind]`, and later code (always or -- conservatively -- at least mostly) later increments `optind` before returning.

Hence consider this program:

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct option longopts[] = {
    { "foo", no_argument, NULL, 'F' },
    { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 }
  };
  int c;

  do {
    int curind = optind;
    c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "f", longopts, NULL);
    switch (c) {
    case 'f':  printf("-f\n");  break;
    case 'F':  printf("--foo\n");  break;
    case '?':
      if (optopt)  printf("bad short opt '%c'\n", optopt);
      else  printf("bad long opt \"%s\"\n", argv[curind]);
      break;
    case -1:
      break;
    default:
      printf("returned %d\n", c);
      break;
    }
  } while (c != -1);

  return 0;
}
```

> $ ./longopt -f -x --bar --foo
>   -f
>   ./longopt: invalid option -- 'x'
>   bad short opt 'x'
>   ./longopt: unrecognized option '--bar'
>   bad long opt "--bar"
>   --foo

Thus in these cases, by caching the pre-`getopt_long` value of `optind`, we're easily able to print out the same bad options as the `opterr` messages.

This may not be quite right in all cases, as the glibc implementation's use of its own `__nextchar` rather than `argv[optind]` (in the "unrecognized option" case) deserves study, but it should be enough to get you started.

If you think carefully about the relationship between `optind` and the repeated invocations of `getopt_long`, I think printing out `argv[cached_optind]` is going to be pretty safe.  `optopt` exists because for short options you need to know just which character within the word is the problem, but for long options the problem is the *whole* current word (modulo stripping off option arguments of the form `=param`).  And the current word is the one that `getopt_long` is looking at with the (incoming) `optind` value.

In the absence of a guarantee written in the documentation, I would be somewhat less sanguine about taking advantage of the `optopt = 0` behaviour though.

Comment: This looks promising, but upon testing it, it seems that this solution is more sensitive to the argument permutation that `getopt_long` does, at least on my Solaris system. I'm sticking with `optind - 1`.

Comment: If you are very picky (like me), you can remove the parameter before displaying with `char *eq = index(argv[optind-1], '='); if (eq != NULL) *eq = '\0';`.